# store date modified properties in array and copy them to another text file line by line C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a utility that needs to take the date modified properties from one text file and copy it to another text file. I would prefer to use an array to store the date modified properties of the files. Here is what I have so far:

```
 class NewTime
        {
            public DateTime Current { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int counter = 0;

            string line;

                // Read the file and display it line by line.
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]);
                System.IO.StreamWriter filewriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(args[1], false);

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                   string [] pieces = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });
                    if(pieces.Length == 2)
                    {
                        DateTime outDate;
                        if(DateTime.TryParse(pieces[1], out outDate))
                        {
             string[] listOfFiles = { @"D:\blahB.txt", @"C:\blahA.txt"};

                        string[] outputLines = listOfFiles.Select(file => file + " | " + file.GetLastWriteTime(file)).ToArray();
                        file.WriteAllLines("verifications.txt", outputLines);
                        //string outputstring = string.Format(" {0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-ff-tt}", DateTime.Now);
                        //filewriter.WriteLine(pieces[0] + "|" + outputstring);
                        }
                        else
                            filewriter.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    else
                        filewriter.WriteLine(line);

                    System.Console.WriteLine(line);

                    counter++;
                }


                System.Console.WriteLine(LastWriteLine+"blahblah");
                file.Close();
                filewriter.Close();
                System.Console.ReadLine();
            }


        public static string LastWriteLine { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, I don't need to open the first file I'm getting the date modified properties from.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the question?

Comment: How can scan through a bunch of files, get their modified date property without opening them, and then take that date and paste it to another text file line by line.

Comment: And what problems are you having with the current implementation you have posted here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the File.GetLastWriteTime to get the last modification date of a file without opening it:

```
string[] listOfFiles = {@"C:\bin\1.txt", @"C:\bin\desktop.png", @"C:\main.c"};

string[] outputLines = listOfFiles.Select(file => file + " | " + File.GetLastWriteTime(file)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", outputLines);
```

Then you get something like this for output in the output.txt:

```
C:\bin\1.txt | 9/12/2014 12:49:54 PM
C:\bin\desktop.png | 9/6/2014 3:11:27 AM
C:\main.c | 11/24/2013 7:14:38 PM
```

Comment: Glad to be of service. Please rephrase your post so that it's more obvious what the question was (you can delete the code sample, I don't think it's necessary here), and mark this answer as an accepted answer. Then it will be more useful for other people checking this post.

Comment: Alright! But could you check the updated code to see if it looks good? I got a few errors there

Comment: Also, I don't understand the notation you used for "file => file..." Could you please give me a brief explanation?

Comment: It's a lambda expression. It takes a file name as parameter and returns the file name and the last modified date, separated by a | character. If you're looking for people explaining code in an interactive way then you should join one of the chat rooms: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ It's much better than leaving comments here, as most people who read this post won't find them very helpful.